# Time Limit Exceed about max heap

Tags: c++

I want to design a function to find the k biggest elements in a unordered set of N elements with time complexity: `Θ(N+klogN)` on an online judge.

here is a sample:

---

Input

```
LN 1 : N K

LN 2 : N numbers
```

Output

```
LN 1 : K biggest number

LN 2 : Final heap
```

Sample Input

```
10 4
17 19 26 37 30 11 5 29 32 1
```

Sample Output

```
29
26 19 11 17 1 5
```

---

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int i,j,rc,temp,temp1,length,K;
    cin>>length>>K;
    int *heap = new int[length];

    for(i=0;i<length;i++) cin>>heap[i];
    for(i=length/2-1;i>=0;i--){                  //build a max heap first with Θ(N)
        while(!((i>=length/2)&&(i<length))){
            j = 2*i+1;
            rc = 2*i+2;
            if((rc<length)&&(heap[j]<heap[rc])) j=rc;
            if(heap[i]>heap[j]) break;
            temp = heap[i];
            heap[i]=heap[j];
            heap[j]=temp;
            i=j;
        }
    }
    int k,n=length;
    for(k=0;k<K;k++){                         //shiftdown k times to find k biggest 
        temp1=heap[--n];                      //numbers with Θ(klogN)
        heap[n] = heap[0];
        heap[0] = temp1;
        if(n!=0) {
            i=0;
                while(!((i>=n/2)&&(i<n))){
                     j = 2*i+1;
                    rc = 2*i+2;
                    if((rc<n)&&(heap[j]<heap[rc])) j=rc;
                    if(heap[i]>heap[j]) break;
                    temp = heap[i];
                    heap[i]=heap[j];
                    heap[j]=temp;
                    i=j;
                }
            }
        }


    cout<<heap[length-K]<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<length-K;i++)
        cout<<heap[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

It's all right but one of datas is Time Limit Exceed ,I am so confused with how to solve this problem.

Comment: Finding the K smallest elements can be done in `O(N)`, maybe that's your Time Limit problem. Are you sure your heap construction is `O(N)` ?

Comment: Yes,it is confirmed on our textbook.And the time limit is 1 sec.

Comment: Does your textbook say you should use heaps?

Comment: yes,it is also my teacher's request

Comment: I think 1 sec is enough，but I don't know where is wrong..

Comment: I don't think you need that while-in-for construct. It should be doable with a single loop, (size>>1)-1 to 0 for building the initial heap, and sift down should be log n steps.

Comment: (In building the heap that is, but I believe for the case where you get the time limit exceeded, you need to handle reverse sorted data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sift-down operation doesn't seem correct. There shouldn't be two nested loops there. You should just start at the root and keep swapping it with one of its children until it's larger than both. The outer loop `for(i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--)` shouldn't be there (it causes each sift-down to take `O(n)`) - I think you should just set `i` to 0 to start at the root.

Edit: Your heapify operation is too slow as well: You are using the same loop variable `i` for both the outer and inner loop, so it will alternately grow larger and smaller. The inner loop should start with the outer loop's `i`, but shouldn't affect the value of `i` in the outer loop's next iteration. I suggest putting the sift-down operation in its own function. This will both fix this problem, and avoid having sift-down coded twice.

Comment: Yes,you are right.I have corrected it,but the result is still Time limit exeed

Comment: Sure,I have modified it above

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Your comment above is wrong. It says there should not be two loops, when there should. So I definitely didn't copy it.

Comment: Sure you did. My edited question detailed it, that he increases i in the while loop again. You elaborated a bit on it though, granted.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: I didn't elaborate on it... It's simply wrong so there's nothing to elaborate about. I don't see how it's even similar.

Comment: Aki Suihkonen finds out the problem in my code.I am a newcomer of stack overflow and I am sorry for reply so late. The time complexity of the program is alright,but it will go into endless loop in some case.That's the point. And all of your idea is meaningful for me,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Some onlinejudge.org contest I guess. Why don't you share the problem link?

Then we could probably tell whether you really need heapsort, or whether you'd be better of with something like QuickSelect and a good heuristic.

My guess is that a plain heapsort will *not suffice* for one of their test cases.

You probably also need to add optimizations such as checking for presorted data, or reverse sorted data (and data-parts) at the beginning and end. Avoid constructing a heap for these parts, but keep them as is.

Try running heapsort on a **huge *reverse* sorted list**, with large k, IIRC that is a worst case (for a max-heap, any min-heap should be worst case and the other way around).

The typical online judge test cases are usually well designed around such known worst cases. And the time limit is then set so that even with a very good optimized `O(n + k log n)` solution you lose compared to a true `O(n)` solution. They just need to make k large enough. They are from contests, and they want to challenge people by giving them real mean input files!

P.S. You **heap build** also seems to be too complicated. The problem is that you *increase `i`* again. You shouldn't need to do this. By increasing i in the while loop, you cause the bottom-up heap construction to "restart" again multiple times. So your heap build likely no longer is `O(n)`.

Comment: It is not a Valladoloid contest and all description about the problem is put above.
Yes,time limits exceed10%,one of case isn't accepted.but all I can consider is OK  ...

Comment: Actually I don't know what is Valladoloid contest,our online judge is provided by my teacher

Comment: The UVa online judge is at http://uva.onlinejudge.org/ and behaves just like your described it - giving only a "time limit exceeded" error. So I guess your teacher is just forwarding them there...

Comment: Anyway, try to find a shortcut for getting data that is *reverse sorted* and a large `k`. It should be a fairly easy optimization.

Comment: I think you are confusing heapsort with quicksort, which has a `O(n^2)` worst case for some inputs. And even if it was slightly slower on reverse-sorted lists, I don't see the point in optimizing for that because it would still be slow on nearly-reverse-sorted lists.

Comment: @interjay: the problem is that heapsort quite consistently has `O(n log n)` for any input. While presorted data can be handled in `O(n)` trivially. So in order to improve heapsort, it *does* pay off to detect partially presorted data. Take TimSort for example (Java 7, Python). It is a mergesort, with optizations for *runs of already sorted data*.

Comment: Well, the OP says he needs to use heapsort so I went with that. If you wanted to switch algorithms, you could use a selection algorithm that is O(n) for *all* inputs, no need to optimize for one specific case.

Comment: The sentence where I mention alternate algorithm clearly says that we'd need to know more about the actual problem. Plus, presorted data is not just one specific case, but actually a *very* common case. So I can imagine the teacher has a test case to challenge the students this way. It **definitely** is what the usual online judges do. Require such optimizations that come at next to no cost for the default case, but bring an immense gain for a common situation.

Comment: Aki Suihkonen finds out the problem in my code.I am a newcomer of stack overflow and I am sorry for reply so late. The time complexity of the program is alright,but it will go into endless loop in some case.That's the point. And all of your idea is meaningful for me,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check what happens with three difference sequences:

- 1. 4 2 1 2 3 4
- 1. 4 2 4 3 2 1
- 1. 4 2 1 1 1 1

---

```
 int NN=0;
 for(i=length/2-1;i>=0;i--){                  //build a max heap first with Θ(N)
cout << "i=" << i << "\n";
    while(!((i>=length/2)&&(i<length))){
        j = 2*i+1;
        rc = 2*i+2;
        cout << NN++ << " " << j << " " << rc << " " << i << "\n";
        if((rc<length)&&(heap[j]<heap[rc])) j=rc;
        if(heap[i]>heap[j]) break;
        temp = heap[i];
        heap[i]=heap[j];
        heap[j]=temp;
        i=j;
    }
}
```

In the last case the loop will stabilize to j=3; rc=4; i=1;

Perhaps the inner loop should use a separate variable instead of 'i'.